# PopupPanel Glass z-index 1 is always on top?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, gwt

I want to use a GWT PopupPanel to show a form to the user. When there are errors an AbsolutePanel with z-index 1000 should be displayed with the error message. My setup is as follows:

```
<g:PopupPanel glassEnabled="true" glassStyleName="{mystyle.glassStyle}">

</g:PopupPanel>
```

where glassStyle is

```
.glassStyle {
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
}
```

My AbsolutePanel has z-index 10000. If the PopupPanel is open and errors occur the AbsolutePanel is shown but cannot be seen because it under the glass of the PopupPanel. Since the z-index of the AbsolutePanel is higher than the z-index of the glass the AbsolutePanel should be visible. This is not the case. Only if I do not set z-index: 1 on the glassStyle the AbsolutePanel is visible.

How can I achieve that the AbsolutePanel can become visible event if a z-index is set on the glassStyle?

Comment: z-index is not the only rule of which element is on top. Make sure the z-index of the parent node of the element you'd like to be in front also has the higher z-index. It also helps to use stacking order, namely the later declared DOM object is placed on top/front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the same effect that you describe, and I don't use z-index settings at all. You simply show your PopupPanel (e.g. '.center()'), and it will pop up above the panels which have been attached before it.

Try to remove all z-index settings - both on AbsolutePanel and on PopupPanel.